# recycle ui elements

Tags: android, user-interface, reusability

hi to all in my activity layout i use this XML to get an array of buttons

```
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="text tab 1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
                />

            <View 
                android:layout_width="1dp" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"                   
                />

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="text tab 2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
                />

            <View 
                android:layout_width="1dp" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"                   
                />

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="text tab 3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
                />

            <View 
                android:layout_width="1dp" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"                   
                />
```

Considering this copy/paste very ugly, i've created a new xml file named 'tab.xml' and defined as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@color/lightgrey"                   
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Returning to the primary layout, i've substitued the first code with three...

```
<include layout="@layout/tab" />
```

...but now, how can i set the textview text? Trying

```
 <include android:text="text tab 1" layout="@layout/tab" />
```

doesn't works: still no text...

Thanks in advance
L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). Use Fragments API as it is available for all android platforms since 1.6 through SDK Updater (SDK Setup) with label «Android Compatibility package».